# Upload files from my local machine to a Api server using docker & go cli

Tags: docker, go

Hi i recently wrote a cli application in Go lang which uploads files from local machine to a Api server.

I was able to test it on my mac & its working properly.

I want to dockerize the cli this is how my dockerfile looks like

FROM alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY bin/linux/main .

RUN mv /main /usr/local/bin

CMD [ main ]

So now when i run this image on my local now its considering the file system as alpine instead of my mac

So how can i make this work with docker?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to run the CLI in a container?  It will be significantly less convenient to use, particularly if it's currently a self-contained binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind mount a host file system location onto the container via the `--volumes, -v` option. For example, if you want to "bring" the `/tmp` directory from your mac into the container's `/tmp/hosttmp`, you would supply `-v /tmp:/tmp/hosttmp`.

See also: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: I started to go that route but is that the only option how you can dockerize the cli?

Comment: What's the motivation in dockerizing a cli written in go?

Comment: I want the binaries to be distributed somehow one way i know is using git pages but you have to download the binary and unzip it and then use it. Docker uses caching and easy to use and widely used so i thought it would be a better solution.